# Bound on function in disk using Cauchy Estimate

Tags: complex-analysis

Here's the question, which is from Ahlfors Chapter 4.

> Let $f(z)$ be analytic on $|z| < R$ with $|f(z)| \le M$ on that disk. Find a bound for $|f^{(n)}(z)|$ on $|z| \le \rho < R$.

I think this is a duplicate (see [Can I get a better bound on this function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25641/can-i-get-a-better-bound-on-this-function)), but I'm confused by the accepted answer for that question.

When I tried to use the Cauchy integral formula to try to get a bound, it seemed that the distance from a point in the disk to the boundary $|\zeta| = R$ came into play, and I got as an answer
$$|f^{(n)}(z)| \le \frac{n! M}{(R-\rho)^n}$$
instead of
$$|f^{(n)}(z)| \le \frac{n! M}{R^n}$$
(which is the answer in [Can I get a better bound on this function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25641/can-i-get-a-better-bound-on-this-function))

To do a sanity check I tried $f(z) = z^{42}$ on the unit disk: $|f(z)| \le 1$ on the unit disk. For the first derivative $f'(z) = 42z^{41}$. It does not seem that $42|z|^{41} \le \frac{1! 1}{1^1}$ on every smaller disk $|z| \le \rho < R$.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, the bound

$$\frac{n! M}{R^n}$$

is a bound for $f^{(n)}(0)$ only, not for $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant \rho$. For $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant \rho$, the standard estimate yields

$$\left\lvert f^{(n)}(z)\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{n! MR}{(R-\rho)^{n+1}}$$

(which for $\rho > 0$ is not a sharp bound, since all of the circle except at most one point is at a distance $> R-\rho$ from $z$ then). A better, but hard to evaluate bound would be

$$\left\lvert f^{(n)}(z)\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{n!MR}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{\lvert Re^{it} - z\rvert^{n+1}} \leqslant \frac{n! MR}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{\lvert Re^{it} - \rho\rvert^{n+1}}.$$

Comment: To apply the Cauchy Estimates you just have to use Cauchy's Integral Formula ?

Comment: Yes, that's how they are (at least usually) obtained. If the bound on $\lvert f(z)\rvert$ one has is not a global constant but a function - e.g. $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant e^{\lvert z\rvert}$ - a judicious choice of the contour can sometimes get one significantly better estimates than one would obtain from just taking a circle about $0$, but it's still the same principle. One uses the integral formula for the derivatives and estimates the integral.

Comment: but how do we estimate the last integral?