# Show that a nonconstant monic must have modulus $\geqslant 1$ on the boundary of the unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that a nonconstant polynomial with leading coefficient $1$ must have modulus $\geqslant 1$ on the boundary of the unit disk.

I am trying to prove by contradiction, $i.e.$ to show that $p(z) = z^n+\cdots+a_0$ cannot map the closed disk to the open unit disk. But why is this true?

Comment: Do you mean that $\max_{z\in S^1}|p(z)|\geq 1$?

Comment: Yes, that is true

Comment: For Googling purposes, such a polynomial is said to be _monic_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\sup_{|z|=1} |p(z)|<1$, then by Cauchy's bounds, $p^{(n)}(0)<n!$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why can't $p'(0)$ be less than $1$?

Comment: Sorry! Fixed.  Also, the bound I used is in the answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555820/bound-on-function-in-disk-using-cauchy-estimate)

Comment: That is so clever! Thank you very much. Can you give me a bit intuition on this one. Since when i first saw this problem, my first thought is to use the surjectivity of the polynomial. How do you know that we should use Cauchy's bound?

Comment: Cauchy's bound is derived by expressing $f^{(n)}(0)$ as an integral over a circle with via the Cauchy Integral Formula, and then using the bound on $f$ over that circle. So it's very applicable here.